# Animating gradients with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gradient

This will be my list question today.. Is it possible to animate radial gradients in jQuery(using .animate), if yes how?

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kEe3X/)

```
background: -webkit-gradient(
    radial, 50% 50% ,0, 50% 50%, 70, from(rgb(25,25,25)), to(rgb(50,50,50))
);
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522513/animate-css3-gradient-positions-using-jquery

Comment: @SérgioMichels I haven't seen that one, but the guy haven't got right answer so..?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this by default in jQuery, you can't even animate flat colors without the corresponding plugin.

Animating gradients is tough because of the syntax differences between browsers.  I wrote a plugin for a very specific case that may be useful to you.  It's for a linear gradient but you can tweak it for radial.

```
jQuery.fx.step.gradient = function(fx) {
    if (fx.state == 0) { //On the start iteration, convert the colors to arrays for calculation.
        fx.start = fx.elem.style.background.match(/\d+/g); //Parse original state for numbers.  Tougher because radial gradients have more of them
        fx.start[0] = parseInt(fx.start[0]);
        fx.start[1] = parseInt(fx.start[1]);
        fx.start[2] = parseInt(fx.start[2]);
        fx.end = fx.end.match(/\d+/g);
        fx.end[0] = parseInt(fx.end[0]);
        fx.end[1] = parseInt(fx.end[1]);
        fx.end[2] = parseInt(fx.end[2]);
    }

    fx.elem.style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(" + [
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[0] - fx.start[0])) + fx.start[0]), 255), 0),
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[1] - fx.start[1])) + fx.start[1]), 255), 0),
        Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[2] - fx.start[2])) + fx.start[2]), 255), 0)
        ].join(",") + ")," + "rgb(0,0,0))";
}

$(this).animate({"gradient": "rgb(0, 255, 0)"});
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/TXXG9/)

You probably want to create two functions, one for the inner color (`jQuery.fx.step.innerColor`) and one for the outer (`jQuery.fx.step.outerColor`) which would be called like this:

```
$(this).animate({"innerColor": "rgb(25,25,25)",
                 "outerColor": "rgb(50,50,50)"});
```