# Is there a way to animate a hover class in jquery without using plugins/ui kits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a roll over effect on a `<h3>Some header</h3>` and I want the background to fadein/fadeout nicely on hover.

its normal state is:

```
h3 {
background: none;
}
```

and the hover is a css3 animation:

```
h3:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.25, #FFFFFF),
        color-stop(1, #FCFCFC)
    );
}
```

since I have so many rules - I can't do it in jQuery simple animatie (or can I?).

Can it be done without using any plugins or jQuery ui kits? Or - is it possible to achieve it in a css3 animation? I tried css3 animtation by adding to h3 this code, but it made weird effects and not at all the simple fadein:

```
h3 {
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* IE10? */
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EsZwN/) with jQuery.

CSS:

```
h3 {
    margin: 10px;
}
div.h3_bg {
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #FF0000 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FF0000 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FF0000 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FF0000 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FF0000 25%, #FCFCFC 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.25, #FF0000),
        color-stop(1, #FCFCFC)
    );
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    $("body")
        .append(
            $('<div>', {class:"h3_bg"})
                .width($(this).outerWidth())
                .height($(this).outerHeight())
                .hide()
                .css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: $(this).offset().top,
                    left: $(this).offset().left,
                    zIndex: -1
                })
        );
    $(this).hover(
        function() {
            $("div.h3_bg").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
        },
        function() {
            $("div.h3_bg").eq($(this).index()).fadeOut();
        }
   );
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but an explanation wud have been nice. To ad to, CSS 3 transitions are not supported for `background: gradient` - to `background: different gradient`

Comment: @OmShankar ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done in pure CSS2.1 + CSS3 without jQuery.

http://cssdesk.com/MGyKp

The top is without extra markup, the bottom is with an extra span. It does not work well in Safari, sadly, but fine in Firefox.

For the cross-browser experience, the jQuery solution in this thread is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 headers, 1 with the background, 1 without. Fade between the 2 using jQuery. Would work with all browsers afaik.

You can pass multiple attributes to a jQuery animation function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Not sure if you can animate opacity for gradient backgrounds though?

Comment: Animating css3-gradient in jQuery is not possible - it was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522513/animate-css3-gradient-positions-using-jquery